# flutter screen build a screen flow with go_router & flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

I'm trying to build a multi screen register using go_router and flutter_bloc
and collect data from screens as we move further into the stack

so basically the user will

- land on the first screen
- enter the name, email...
- goes to the second screen
- enter screen fields, date of birth, account type, ...

note the first screen is different from the first one so I can't just use a PageView or something
how do I achieve such a behaviour

I tried to use a ShellRoute and have a persistant BlocProvider on all screens and collect data

my router config

```dart
final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _registerNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _registerFieldsNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      path: "/login",
      builder: (context, state) {
        return const LoginPage();
      },
    ),
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: _registerNavigatorKey,
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      builder: (context, state, child) => RegisterPage(child: child),
      routes: [
        ShellRoute(
          navigatorKey: _registerFieldsNavigatorKey,
          parentNavigatorKey: _registerNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state, child) => RegisterFieldsPage(child: child),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              parentNavigatorKey: _registerFieldsNavigatorKey,
              path: "/register/fields1",
              builder: (context, state) => const RegisterFields1(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              parentNavigatorKey: _registerFieldsNavigatorKey,
              path: "/register/fields2",
              builder: (context, state) => const RegisterFields2(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: _registerNavigatorKey,
          path: "/register/terms_and_conditions",
          builder: (context, state) => const TermsAndConditions(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

however I can't push the the ShellRoute stack using `GoRouter.of(context).push("/register/fields2")` I have to use `GoRouter.of(context).go("/register/fields2")` but it clears my navigation history I mean imagine if the user were in the login screen and wants to go back ?

is there any other solution I was think on storing data using SharedPreferences...